# Using jQuery's .show() on a <div> works, but results in frozen .gifs in Firefox if I try to run along with a redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, jquery-events

Currently I have the code:

```
<!-- More html code above -->
<div id="loading" style="display: none;">
    <div align="center">
        <img src="/loading.gif" style="padding:10px;" />
        <div id="lmessage"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- More html code below -->
<!-- ...... -->

<script>
$("#buttonSubmit").click(function () { 
$("#loading").show();
window.location = "/cgi-bin/somscript.py?value="+$('[name=someelement]').val();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically, I want the div to appear upon the button being clicked. This works, but the .gif (normally animated) only displays the first frame and freezes. The image is properly animated in Safari, but on Firefox it is not. Does anyone know why?

EDIT: Updated the code. If I remove the `window.location`, the gif works.... why? Do I need to use `.delegate` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `window.location.href = url` instead of `window.location = url` ([w3Schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp))

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code to just use a form submit as opposed to a redirect, but this would have helped!

Answer (score 0):

There is a config setting in firefox called: image.animation_mode

So if you go to about:config from the address bar in firefox.  See what your animation mode is set to.

Comment: default: normal . And removing the window.location fixes the issue, so it's something to do with that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using window.location create an iframe and set its "src" instead.